# Can we share multiple photos on Twitter at once through Twitter API for iOS?

Tags: image, twitter, sharing

Can we share multiple photos on Twitter in one request or we can only upload one image at a time by using Twitter API in iOS?
I had a look in the documentation of Twitter API but I didn't find such information.

Comment: My guess would be if it's not documented you can't.

Comment: @stonedsquirrel I am also thinking that but I need a proof for that. That is why I asked here.

Comment: It's kind of hard to proof that something doesn't exist ;-) Maybe it exists and nobody knows about it. Just saying if you don't get a positive answer in some time, that's probably a "no".

Answer (score 2):

You can share only 1 image at a time.so to share multiple images you have to loop it.

i have done something as below to share 3 images

```
switch (indexImage) {
            case 0:
                img = imgBar;// image name
                break;

            case 1:
                img = [self captureView:graphView inSize:graphView.frame.size];

                break;
            case 2:
                img = [self captureView:otherGraphView inSize:otherGraphView.frame.size];

                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
```